# Simplifying a switch case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, swipe

I have a rather repetitive switch case statement and in my quest to learn the simplest way of doing things, I wanted to turn to SO and see if there is a more elegant solution to the following:

```
        switch(id)
        {
            case 'ib-02a':
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-02b');
                break;
            case 'ib-02b':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-02a');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-02c');
                break;
            case 'ib-02c':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-02b');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-02d');
                break;
            case 'ib-02d':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-02c');
            break;

            case 'ib-03a':
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-03b');
                break;
            case 'ib-03b':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-03a');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-03c');
                break;
            case 'ib-03c':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-03b');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('ib-03d');
                break;
            case 'ib-03d':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('ib-03c');
            break;

            case 'pb-05a':
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('pb-05b');
                break;
            case 'pb-05b':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('pb-05a');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('pb-05c');
                break;
            case 'pb-05c':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('pb-05b');
                if(direction == 'left')
                    setHash('pb-05d');
                break;
            case 'pb-05d':
                if(direction == 'right')
                    setHash('pb-05c');
            break;
        }
```

I'm reading swipe events, and if the ID of the element I am swiping on matches either ib-02*, ib-03*, or pb-05*, I am calling a setHash function for the appropriate ID. If I'm swiping on *a, I swipe left to *b. If I'm swiping on *b, I swipe right to *a and left to *c. So on and so forth, always between *a and *d.

There must be a less repetitive way to do this, but I'm not sure exactly what the best approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about mapping them to an object? Then just use the `setHash` with the retrieved value.

```
var ids = {
    'pb-05c' : {
        left : 'pb-05d',
        right : 'pb-05b'
    }
    ...
}

function setHashes(id,direction){
    if(id && ids[id]){
        id = ids[id];
        if(direction && id[direction]){
            setHash(id[direction]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's all retrieval and no condition evaluation, which can be good for performance.

Comment: This code would have issues (that the original code did not) if the id or direction did not exist in your data structure.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, I was just thinking about that.

Comment: I love this, but am wondering how to get around the issue of if there is no id or direction passed?

Comment: @Greg-J updated my answer. You just check if id and direction are there.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 major cases that are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, you can base your switch statement on these strings, try this:

```
var c = id.slice(0, 5); // "ib-02" or "ib-03" or "ib-04" ...
var which = id.slice(-1); // "a" or "b" or "c" or "d"
switch(which) {
    case 'a':
       if(direction == 'left')
             setHash(c+'b');
          break;
    case 'b':
       if(direction == 'right')
             setHash(c+'a');
       if(direction == 'left')
             setHash(c+'c');
          break;
    case 'c':
       if(direction == 'right')
             setHash(c+'b');
       if(direction == 'left')
             setHash(c+'d');
          break;
    case 'd':
       if(direction == 'right')
            setHash(c+'c');
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the whole thing data table driven like this:

```
var logicData = {
    // format is the id first and then an array with the left, then right value for the hash
    // leave an item as an empty string if you don't ever want to go that direction
    'ib-02a': ['ib-02b', ''],
    'ib-02b': ['ib-02c', 'ib-02a'],
    'ib-02c': ['ib-02d', 'ib-02d']
    // fill in the rest of the data table here
};

function setNewHash(id, direction) {
    var hash, data = logicData[id];
    if (data) {
        if (direction == 'left') {
            hash = data[0];
        } else if (direction == 'right') {
            hash = data[1];
        }
        if (hash) {
            setHash(hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id='ib-02a'; //you have string id, this one is for demo
id=[id.slice(0,--id.length), id.charAt(--id.length)];

switch(id[1]){
    case 'a':
        if(direction == 'left'){setHash(id[0]+'b');}
        break;
    case 'b':
        if(direction =='right'){setHash(id[0]+'a');}
        if(direction == 'left'){setHash(id[0]+'c');}
        break;
    case 'c':
        if(direction == 'right'){setHash(id[0]+'b');}
        if(direction == 'left'){setHash(id[0]+'d');}
        break;
    case 'd':
        if(direction == 'right'){setHash(id[0]+'c');}
        break;
}
```

If case b and c are only 'left' or 'right' you could use an `else` in those if statements.

Comment: forgot to mention: this creates no new variables in it's parent scope and `id` can simply be rebuilt afterwards if needed by: `id=id.join('');`

Answer (score 1):

I like the general direction of undefined and GitaarLab where they actually solved the algorithm and just implemented the algorithm.  To review, the algorithm is basically that `left` increments the final letter and `right` decrements the final letter of the id, but you don't go below `a` or above `d`.  So, I did a compact implementation of that where I convert the last letter to a number and increment or decrement it directly rather than using if/else or case statements:

```
function setNewHash(id, direction) {
    var base = id.substr(0, 5);
    var tag = id.charCodeAt(5), newTag;
    var nav = {left: 1, right: -1};
    var delta = nav[direction];
    if (delta) {
        tag += delta;
        newTag = String.fromCharCode(tag);
        if (newTag >= 'a' && newTag <= 'd') {
            setHash(base + newTag);
        }
    }
}
```

Working test case: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gwfLD/

Comment: Thank you for the compliment!! I also like your reusable function. I was also looking at the `direction` part, but did not know it's exact constraints. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could chunk up the id into different parts, then rebuild them right before you do `setHash`.

```
function chunkId(id) {
    // use a regex or string split or something to convert
    // "ib-05a" to ["ib-05", "a"]
    return ["ib-05", "a"];
}

function next(str) {
    // return the next letter in the alphabet here
    return "b";
}

function prev(str) {
    // return the prev letter in the alphabet here
    return "b";
}

function swipe (id, direction) {
    var array = chunkId(id);
    // you can only swipe left if not on "d"
    if (direction === "left" && id[1] != "d") {
        setHash(id[0] + next(id[1])); // build hash based on next character
    }
    // you can only swipe right if not on "a"
    if (direction === "right" && id[1] != "a") {
        setHash(id[0] + prev(id[1])); // build hash based on prev character
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the id and direction checks to make it clearer:

```
switch (direction) {
  case 'left':
    switch (id) {
      case 'ib-02a': setHash('ib-02b'); break;
      case 'ib-02b': setHash('ib-02c'); break;
      case 'ib-02c': setHash('ib-02d'); break;
      case 'ib-03a': setHash('ib-03b'); break;
      case 'ib-03b': setHash('ib-03c'); break;
      case 'ib-03c': setHash('ib-03d'); break;
      case 'pb-05a': setHash('pb-05b'); break;
      case 'pb-05b': setHash('pb-05c'); break;
      case 'pb-05c': setHash('pb-05d'); break;
    }
    break;
  case 'right':
    switch (id) {
      case 'ib-02b': setHash('ib-02a'); break;
      case 'ib-02c': setHash('ib-02b'); break;
      case 'ib-02d': setHash('ib-02c'); break;
      case 'ib-03b': setHash('ib-03a'); break;
      case 'ib-03c': setHash('ib-03b'); break;
      case 'ib-03d': setHash('ib-03c'); break;
      case 'pb-05b': setHash('pb-05a'); break;
      case 'pb-05c': setHash('pb-05b'); break;
      case 'pb-05d': setHash('pb-05c'); break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Then you can simplify if by splitting the id:

```
var first = id.substr(0, 5);
var last = id.substr(6);
switch (direction) {
  case 'left':
    switch (last) {
      case 'a': setHash(first + 'b'); break;
      case 'b': setHash(first + 'c'); break;
      case 'c': setHash(first + 'd'); break;
    }
    break;
  case 'right':
    switch (last) {
      case 'b': setHash(first + 'a'); break;
      case 'c': setHash(first + 'b'); break;
      case 'd': setHash(first + 'c'); break;
    }
    break;
}
```